# How do you change Object values with Flux Stores?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

Since Facebook [removed Flux's MapStore](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/751f03c8d02149b6e4f23fba41998276082507d5/CHANGELOG.md#300), I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to mutate an object in its store.

ReduceStore is supposed to be able to handle this problem, and The Pro-React book by Cássio de Sousa Antonio has several examples of ReduceStore, but none of them highlight this functionality, and I'm a bit lost.

```js
class MyObjectStore extends Flux.ReduceStore {

  getInitialState(){
    return {
      foo: '',
      bar: '',
      baz:''
    };
  }

  reduce(state, action){
    switch (action.type) {
      case constants.CHANGE_FOO:
        return state.set('foo', action.value)
      case constants.CHANGE_BAR:
        return state.set('bar', action.value)
      case constants.CHANGE_BAZ:
        return state.set('baz', action.value)
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
}

export default new MyObjectStore(AppDispatcher);

// => TypeError: state.set is not a function
```

I tried:

```js
state.foo = action.value;
 return state;
```

but doing this doesn't trigger any changes.

**UPDATED:**

Using Immutable worked:

```js
import Immutable, {Map} from 'immutable';

class MyStore extends ReduceStore {

  getInitialState(){
    return Map({
      foo: '',
      bar: '',
      baz: ''
    });
  }

  reduce(state, action){
    switch (action.type) {
      case constants.CHANGE_FOO:
        return state.set('foo', action.value)
      case constants.CHANGE_BAR:
        return state.set('bar', action.value)
      case constants.CHANGE_BAZ:
        return state.set('baz', action.value)
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
}
```

However, now in the rendering methods, I have to be careful to use Map's getter functions, ex:

```js
const bar = this.props.foo.get('bar');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial state is a plain object, but your `reduce` seems to be opperating on Immutable objects. This means when `reduce` is called the first time, `state` is a plain object with no `set` property, giving you the TypeError you mention. Changing your `getInitialState` to return an immutable map (eg wrap what you have in `Map(...)`) will fix it.